# Call C++ dll from two machine

Tags: c#, c++

I have one C++ dll that want call this from two machines.
One machine sends some data to this dll and I want read this data from dll.
When read data from second machine it returns only zero.
For solve this problem, I must use shared memory? or need do any change in my c++ dll?
Regards.

Comment: *One machine sends some data to this dll* How can you send data to *dll* ? Explain pls

Comment: Are you trying to use the DLL to send message between machines?

Comment: First process send data to dll and I want read this data from second process. But second process only returns zero.

Comment: you can use WCF to communicate between two programs on the same or on different machines

Answer (score 1):

DLL's are non executable. You will need a program which loads this DLL and uses it.
To communicate across computers common practice is to use sockets. Since you marked C# i'll assume you are on windows.
So you can use [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (C++ Win32) or [System.net.sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for sending data across computers.

Shared memory such as [memory files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) will not work cross computer.

Comment: Both process are in same computer. one side is C++ and another side is C++/C#. For example first process send 1 to dll and when I want read number with second process dll returns zero instead 1.

Comment: You haven't stated what your method of sending is. Sockets are still valid for a single computer. You will need to give a lot more information if you want a more in depth answer. Add the information to your question. Your question also clearly states `one machine`, `second machine` which means there are two machines.

Comment: Yes, I have two machines. First machine is MetaTrader software, that call my dll and send data to dll. Second Machine is script by C# or C++, that call dll for read data that sent by first machine.

Comment: Unfortunately there is still no information as to how you are actually communicating. Try including some code samples and a description of the mechanism in your question using the edit functionality.